# Dance Dance Revolution Floor Sensor -- How Does It Work?

Tags: sensor, how-does-it-work

I'm attempting to build my own dance pad, and after researching a lot of DIY solutions, I decided to see what the original arcade machines use. They use 16 of [these](https://www.betsonparts.com/dance-dance-revolution-floor-sensor.html) sensors per stage --

[image]

My question is, how do these sensors work? Are there switches impregnated in the rubber/silicone?

These sensors could be proprietary, but there may be something else out there that works similarly.

Buying 16 of these is cost-prohibitive, so if I can get away with casting some membrane tactile switches in silicone I certainly will.

If nobody knows, I will order one, dissect it, and post results here.

Comment: It could have some kind of FSR (Force Sensitive Resistor) in there. The padding could be to stop it getting damaged. I would look into these maybe, as they can be discreet and they work well.

Comment: Looks like a long membrane switch covered in a nerf-style foam so that it would capture pressure applied at any point along the switch. Either a membrane switch or something closer to the design of a strain gage inside there https://www.omega.com/en-us/sensors-and-sensing-equipment/pressure-and-strain/strain-gauges/p/SGD-EXTRA-LONG

Comment: @nvuono Strain gauge seems too high end

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't actually be a strain gage but I think if you were going to make your own DIY membrane switch you might use a similar pattern. Digikey had a DIY guide https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/make-a-custom-membrane-keypad-for-arduino/4988a4a4e78a495d8d03212e1e5aee9e

Comment: Now why do we have a "how does it work" tag? Sounds like a meta tag... most questions are asking about how something works, from Ohm's law to some membrane switch.

Comment: *If nobody knows, I will order one, dissect it, and post results here.* - I just wonder how many dancing EEs will be interested in what you post? Given also that the thing doesn't have a data sheet, it's unlikely that many pro EEs will be interested. Just saying. VTC

Comment: Could be a simple ribbon switch, a Normally Open switch that closes when pressed. Something similar was used inside Omega swimming touch pads in the 1970s. Don't know what technology they use now.